# How do I get the guild Id that user/member join to

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm using discordX events that triggers a member join .

```js
@Discord()
abstract class MemberEvent {
    @On({ event: "guildMemberAdd" })
    private async onJoin(member: GuildMember): Promise<void> {
        console.log(member)
        console.log(member.guild)
        console.log(member.guild.id)
```

When I try to get member - everything works fine, I get the full format information

```js
[
  GuildMember {
    guild: Guild {
      id: '...',
      name: '...',
      icon: null,
...
    user: User {
      id: '...',
      bot: true,
      system: false,
...
  }
]
```

But when I try to get `member.guild` or `member.guild.id` for further use - I get `undefined` for `member.guild` or `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')` for `member.guild.id`.

`Server Members Intent` on discord dev portal is enabled, also `GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers` is prescribed on bot initialisation

Answer (score 1):

DiscordX handles events a bit differently from discord.js.
You need to wrap in an array and use ArgsOf
`[member]: ArgsOf<"guildMemberAdd">`

Like this

```js
@Discord()
abstract class MemberEvent {
    @On({ event: "guildMemberAdd" })
    private async onJoin([member]: ArgsOf<"guildMemberAdd">): Promise<void> {
        console.log(member)
        console.log(member.guild.id)
```